.NET Core: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception' error when using a .cert file
I am trying to call a service with .NET Core. At first, I used a .cer file, but it was not working.
I tried to set ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback as shown here, I tried everything like comments, but I keep getting an error:
   public static HttpClient getClient(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   {  
       var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
       handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
       handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;  //delegate { return true; };

       //= (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
       handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
       var client = new HttpClient(handler);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       return client;
   }

I also tried:
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  =
      (message, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
          if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
          {
              return true;   //Is valid
          }

          if (cert.GetCertHashString() == "99E92D8447AEF30483B1D7527812C9B7B3A915A7")
          {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      };

However, when I used a .p12 certificate with a password, it worked:
var cert = new X509Certificate2("app_test_chain.p12","password");

But whenever I use the .cert certificate, it does not work:
var cert = new X509Certificate2("app_test_chain.cer");

This is the error I get:

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

and in logs:
A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013.
And trace:
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Source=System.Net.Http
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.<EstablishSslConnectionAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\ConnectHelper.cs:line 83
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 484
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<ConnectAsync>d__103.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpConnectionPool.cs:line 1375
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 487
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__105.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpConnectionPool.cs:line 1459
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 484
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<AddHttp11ConnectionAsync>d__79.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpConnectionPool.cs:line 532
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.<WaitWithCancellationAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in System.Threading.Tasks\TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation.cs:line 17
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 484
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.HttpConnectionWaiter`1.<WaitForConnectionWithTelemetryAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpConnectionPool.cs:line 199
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 484
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__89.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpConnectionPool.cs:line 1014
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() in System.Threading.Tasks\ValueTask.cs:line 484
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\RedirectHandler.cs:line 24
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext() in System.Net.Http\HttpClient.cs:line 567
   at TestApp.AddOns.TestSecApi.Core.SecApi.GetRolesOfApplication(String zone_name, String application) in C:\development\testsecapi\GondorSecApi.cs:line 411
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\development\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 21

Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can continue using the .cer file in my code?

The client certificate needs a private key attached, you can't use a bare crt certificate.

The certificate is already installed on the machine, and the same code works with .NET Framework 4.8

If it's installed in the certificate store why are you using a file to create the X509Certificate2? You should retrieve it from the X509Store. If so, possibly the .NET4.8 code is managing to retrieve the private key from the store and attach it, whereas .NET Core is not. Either way, just get the certificate with private key from the right place.

Since I plan to run my code on Linux in the future, it needs to be cross-platform. While reading it from store works well on Windows, it does not function correctly on Linux.

OK so what's stopping you using the .p12 file? Why do you think the .cer file is enough? It doesn't contain the private key and you need that.

.p12 need password, we are not allowed to use passwords in our code

Well you have to store the private key somewhere. Either you store it in a file or in a store. Linux does have user-level certificate stores, which you can access using X509Store. Not sure why you are having difficulty with that. Also you can create a p12 with a blank password, but that's just as insecure as embedding the password in the app.
